# using singleton for creating listener object not working

Tags: java, android, singleton, listener, observer-pattern

i am using a singleton that for some reason is not working, can't figure out why

```
  private static ConnectionUtility instance;

  public static ConnectionUtility getInstance() {
     if(instance == null){
         instance = new ConnectionUtility();
     }
     return instance;
  }
```

in the code shown above, the second time the execution of this code takes place, instance is not null, an instance has been created already, so on the second time this code is executed it should go to the return instance line directly and skip the instance = new ConnectionUtility() line.  however on second iteration it will try to create another instance of the ConnectionUtility object when one already exists. why is it doing this?  how to fix this problem?

full code posted below: for 3 classes ConnectionUtility and MultiThreader and Start

```
  public class Start {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

  ConnectionUtility.getInstance();

 } // end main

} // end Start
```

---

```
    public class ConnectionUtility extends javax.swing.JFrame
    implements  MultiThreader.OnSendResultListener {

    private static ConnectionUtility instance;

    public static ConnectionUtility getInstance() {
     if(instance == null){
         instance = new ConnectionUtility();
     }
     return instance;
    }

   private ConnectionUtility() {

     initComponents();
     this.setVisible(true);

     serverRunner();

     File fileOne = new File("C:/DBFiles");
     if(!fileOne.exists()){
         fileOne.mkdir();
     }

     File fileTwo = new File("C:/DBFilesOut");
     if(!fileTwo.exists()){
         fileTwo.mkdir();
     }  

  }
public void serverRunner(){

      runner = true;

       try {
        serversocket = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);

         System.out.println();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionUtility.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

      while(runner){

         try {
             socket = serversocket.accept();

   addAndDisplayTextToString("new connection, inet socket address >>> " + socket.getPort());
   System.out.println(displayString);


         } catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(ConnectionUtility.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

      //     MultiThreader multi = new MultiThreader(socket, this);
         MultiThreader multi = new MultiThreader(socket);
           Thread t = new Thread(multi);
           t.start();

      }  // end while runner loop

  } // end serverRunner method

   public static void addAndDisplayTextToString(String setString){

   StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder(displayString);

   setString = setString + "\n";

   if(stb.toString() == ""){
   stb.append(setString);
   }else if(stb.toString() != ""){
       stb.insert(0, setString);
   }

    int counter = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < stb.length(); i++){
      if(stb.substring(i, i + 1).equals("\n")){
           counter++;
      }
  }

  // get the last index of "\n"
  int lastIndex = stb.lastIndexOf("\n");

  int maximum = 4;
  if(counter >= maximum){

      stb.delete(lastIndex, stb.length());
      System.out.println();

  }

  displayString = stb.toString();

 }

@Override
public void onStringResult(String transferString) {
   addAndDisplayTextToString(transferString);
   jTextArea1.setText(displayString);
   System.out.println("RETURNED TRING " + transferString);

}

} // class ConnectionUtility
```

---

```
public class MultiThreader implements Runnable {


  public MultiThreader(Socket s) {
    socket = s;
stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
    listener = ConnectionUtility.getInstance();

}

@Override
public void run() {

    long serialNumber = 0;
    int bufferSize = 0;

     // get input streams
    try {
    bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MultiThreader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    sendStatus("New connection strarted");

     // read in streams from server
    try {        
        fileSizeFromClient = dis.readInt();
         sendStatus("File size from client " + fileSizeFromClient);
         serialNumber = dis.readLong();
         sendStatus("Serial mumber from client " + serialNumber);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MultiThreader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

     try {
        bufferSize = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
         sendStatus("Buffer size " + bufferSize);
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MultiThreader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    String serialString = String.valueOf(serialNumber);

    File fileDirectory = new File("C:" + File.separator + "DOWNLOAD" + File.separator + serialNumber + File.separator);
    fileDirectory.mkdir();

    File file = new File("C:" + File.separator + "DOWNLOAD" + File.separator + serialNumber + File.separator + "JISSend.pdf");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MultiThreader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MultiThreader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    int count = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileSizeFromClient];

    try {

      int totalBytesRead = 0;

       while(totalBytesRead < fileSizeFromClient){
       int bytesRemaining = fileSizeFromClient - totalBytesRead;
       int bytesRead = dis.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(buffer.length, bytesRemaining));

        if(bytesRead == -1){
           break;
         }else{

            dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

        }
    }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MultiThreader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {

            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MultiThreader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        stpe.schedule(new CompareFiles(), 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        stpe.schedule(new CloseResources(), 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  } // end run method

  public class CompareFiles implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

  int returnInt = 0;
  FileInputStream fis = null;

    File file = new File("C:/DOWNLOAD/JISSend.pdf");
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MultiThreader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

        int fileLength = (int) file.length();

        sendStatus("Size of database file sent " + fileLength);

         if(fileLength == fileSizeFromClient){

         sendStatus("File sent to server, Successful");   
         returnInt = 1;

         }else if(fileLength != fileSizeFromClient){

         sendStatus("ERROR, file send failed");   
         returnInt = 2;

         }
        try {
            dos.writeInt(returnInt);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MultiThreader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } // end run method
   } // end of class comparefiles

   public class CloseResources implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

    try {
    fos.flush();
    bis.close();
    bos.close();
    dis.close();
    dos.close();
    socket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MultiThreader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    } // end run method
  } // end of class closeResources

   public interface OnSendResultListener {
    public void onStringResult(String transferString);
  }

  public void sendStatus(String status){
 listener.onStringResult(status);
  }

  } // end class mulitthreader
```

EDIT:  here is the where the second call for the ConnectionUitlity object is happening, in the constructor of the Multithreader class, when it is called for creation of a new multithreader class in connectionUtility

```
 public MultiThreader(Socket s) {

    socket = s;
stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
    listener = ConnectionUtility.getInstance();


}
```

Comment: Where are you getting 2 instances?

Comment: Delete the code which is not need, so that it will be more clear to us. Plus I can't see in code that you are creating instance anywhere except `getInstance()` method.

Comment: i removed code that does help in the explanation, and added the third class called Start that calls the getInstance() method,  the only place the getInstance() method is called is in the main java method in Start class for starting the first instance of the class and it is called in listener = ConnectionUtility.getInstance(); because it is needed for the listener object.

Comment: in the connection utility class when it instantiates a new MultiThreader class object is where the compiler tells me that the second instantiation of the ConnectionUtilty object happens, in the Multitreader constructor

Comment: In multithreaded environment your `getInstance` method should be `synchronized`, or use the double checked locking. Also the constructors should be `private`, to avoid creation out of the class. You should check http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-with-examples

Comment: @omainegra You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Fildor Done as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From comment**

In multithreaded environment your `getInstance` method should be synchronized, or use the double checked locking. Also the constructors should be private, to avoid creation out of the class. You should check http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-with-examples